# Variable Ranges in Lambda functions with Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, google-sheets-formula

I have this lambda map formula (simplified for the question). It works well, but chatgpt suggested me that I can change IF(COUNTA(a;b;c;d;e)>0;" // ";"") for IF(COUNTA(a:e)>0;" // ";"") so i can simplify lambda variable ranges. But when I tried in sheets, it automatically change (a:e) for (A:E), and coloured, so I suppose that is interpreted as columns A:E (and I get a #value error.

```
=MAP(
  AP3:AP;Q3:Q;AR3:AR;AT3:AT;BF3:BF;
  LAMBDA(a;b;c;d;e;
    TEXTJOIN(" / "; TRUE;
      a;
      b;
      c;
      d;
      e;
    ) & IF(COUNTA(a;b;c;d;e)>0;" // ";"")
  )
)
```

Is it possible to achieve what I want and get a:e as variable range? It's a large formula and i could simplify things a lot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What about if you try to do the same but with BYROW?. It will process all your ranges row by row, and with curly brackets you stack them (if you already have HSTACK you can do the same without the curly brackets). If I understand correctly you could do something like this:

```
=BYROW(
  {AP3:AP\Q3:Q\AR3:AR\AT3:AT\BF3:BF};
  LAMBDA(r;
    TEXTJOIN(" / "; TRUE;
     r
    ) & IF(COUNTA(r)>0;" // ";"")
  )
)
```